# Is it possible to embed ODP (OpenDocument) in html page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, browser, libreoffice, opendocument, openoffice-impress

In my html, I have the following object tag.

```
<object type="application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation" data="/Media/4/4/slides.odp" 
    width="800"
    height="600">
    <param name="src" value="/Media/4/4/slides.odp" />
    <param name="autoplay" value="true" />
    <param name="autoStart" value="1" />
</object>
```

However, it doesn't display in the browser, but it does show a dialog asking if I want to open or save.

I have LibreOffice installed, but is there another viewer I need.  Is this even possible?
I'm trying to serve it with C# MVC4.5

Answer (score 0):

You might have to enable the Browser Plugin in the LO options (Menu "`Tools`" -> "`Options`" -> "`Internet`"):

[image]